# Jest won't transform the module - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, babel-jest, ts-jest

I couldn't get rid of this `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error no matter what I have tried and it got so frustrating. Is there anybody out here solved this issue? I have read a million stackoverflow and github issue threads. No clear solutions.

This is a React, Typescript, Webpack project. I am trying to test a module. But Jest won't transform the **module to plain javascript** somehow.

### The error I get is

```
/Users/me/dev/Project/project/node_modules/variables/src/variables.js:12
    import './main.js';
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

      17 | 
      18 | */
    > 19 | import { GlobalVars } from 'variables'
         | ^
      20 | 
      21 | export const Vars = new GlobalVars()
      22 |
```

### What I have tried to solve this (and didn't work):

- Using `env` setup in `babel.config`: `env.test.preset: ['@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs']`
- modifying `transform` setup in Jest configuration as `'^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest', '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'` and all other possibilities around this.
- In Jest configuration, `testPathIgnorePatterns`, `transformIgnorePatterns`
- Using  `.babel.config.js` instead of `.babelrc.js`

...and more.

### I have this setup:

**package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

**.babelrc.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { targets: { node: 'current' } }],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/proposal-class-properties',
    '@babel/transform-regenerator',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals',
    'react-hot-loader/babel',
  ],
}
```

**variables.ts**

```js
import { GlobalVars } from 'variables'

export const Vars = new GlobalVars()
```

**variables.spec.ts**

```js
import { Vars } from './variables.ts'

describe('Test The Package', () => {
  it('Should accept new variables', () => {
    Vars.newVariable = 'new variable'
    expect(Vars.newVariable).toEqual('new variable')
  })
})
```

Any idea on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Try experimental ESM running node with `--experimental-vm-modules` as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70200697/5078874

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Even though I have tried them separately, I haven't tried them together (`transform` and `transformIgnorePatterns`). So this jest configuration solved my issue:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "transform": {
      "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
    ]
  },
```

### My mistakes were:

1. Not using `transform` and `transformIgnorePatterns` **together**.
2. And defining `babel-jest` as the transformer instead of `ts-jest` (I guess that is a problem when the **preset** of jest is defined as `ts-jest`. Because if I change it to be `babel-jest` it throws the same error again.):

```
--- "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest"
+++ "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
```

Comment: For anyone using babel instead of ts-jest, also rename your .babelrc to babel.config.json see: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case

This way you might not need an extra transform if you are already using babel.

Comment: which jest config? There is a jest.config.js file, there is jest config section in package.json. Where is exactly does this configuration reside?

Comment: Super !. I have done this configuration in the package.json and it worked . Thank you

Comment: I'm new jest but I feel like I have tried every suggestion on the internet and this error refuses to go away. I have a sinking feeling that things have changed between jest v26 and v27. Also tried ts-jest.

Comment: This surprisingly does not work for me.. Sad..

Comment: How can we use babel plugins with this setup like: `babel-plugin-transform-vite-meta-env` ?

Comment: I get the error "Module ts-jest in the transform option was not found."

Comment: I didn't have to add anything related to `transform` or `transformIgnorePatterns` but was missing `"preset": "ts-jest"` and `"testEnvironment": "node"`, once I added those my tests worked, thanks!

Answer (score 34):

My issue was different in a way that `jest` would stumle on `.js` files from one of the dependencies in `node_modules` with `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

I had to make sure, that `ts-jest` wouldn't ignore (when transforming) `.js` files in troublesome dependency.

After reading carefully [about presets](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets), I realized, that it leaves them 'as-is' with `preset: 'ts-jest'`. I changed it to `preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts'` and set `"allowJs": true` in `tsconfig.json`.

To not mess up my project's `tsconfig.json`, I have a separate one for `jest`.

In the end, my `jest.config.js` looks mainly like this:

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
    testEnvironment: "node",
    globals: {
        'ts-jest': {
            tsconfig: '<rootDir>/test/tsconfig.json',
        },
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules/(?!troublesome-dependency/.*)",
    ],
}
```

P.S. I didn't need a `transform` field, since the preset is already on it.

P.P.S. I didn't need to introduce any `babel` configuration

Comment: Changing the preset from `ts-jest` to `ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts` was all I needed to get jest running on legacy code I'm migrating to typescript. Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

**Use Vitest.**

I have tried most of the suggestions made here. I found Jest to be quite painful to install correctly, whereas Vitest works out of the box without any config. This is my personal experience. It took me days to get Jest to sort-of work. I had Vitest working immediately after installation.

I don't want to hate on Jest, I actually think it's a wonderful and intuitive testing tool. But ultimately Vitest "Just Works" <sup>(tm)</sup>, and you can use the same simple Jest style API we all have come to love.

Steps (I use pnpm, but of course you could do the same with yarn or npm):

```
pnpm remove jest ts-jest @types/jest
pnpm add -D vite vitest
```

Delete `jest.config.js`, and create `vite.config.ts`:

```
/// <reference types="vitest" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    /* for example, use global to avoid globals imports (describe, test, expect): */
    // globals: true,
  },
})
```

Add to your tests:

```
import { assert, expect, test } from 'vitest'
```

Update your package.json:

```
"test": "vitest",
```

Comment: I gave up on fighting Jest and moved to Vitest that required only `npm i vitest` without any configs.

Comment: 100% agree. I was overjoyed at how quickly and simply I was able to get Vitest working.

Comment: One more here...

Comment: OMG. It. Just. Works. 

Fast.

And watches tests out-of-the box.

Comment: Although, "just use something else" is a terrible SO answer, this really is a much better option than wasting hours trying to make Jest work.

Answer (score 8):

Since Jest is not working with esmodules well, you need to add these configurations in `jest.config.js` to tell Jest to use `commonJS` builds instead

```
moduleNameMapper: {
  '^variables$': 'variables/dist/cjs',
  '^[NAME OF MODULE YOU WANT TO IMPORT]$': '[NAME OF MODULE YOU WANT TO IMPORT]/dist/cjs'
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution? Or give a link to documentation about moduleNameMapper?

Comment: do you have a example of a module? instead of name of module? (The module I'm having problems with does not have a dist/cjs folder. so even if I add `"^ol$": "ol/dist/ol.js"` i still get the error.

Comment: here is an example of this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958968/cannot-use-import-stateament-outside-a-module-with-axios/74297004?r=Saves_UserSavesList#7429700å4

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me.

`npm i ts-jest -D`

Create **jest.config.js** in your root dir

Then add this to it:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "testMatch": [
    "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
    "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't necessarily need to change the transformer from babel-jest to ts-jest.

Instead:

1. Rename your `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case
2. Add transformIgnorePatterns:

```
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
    ]
```

This solved similar problem to me without need to add additional transform patterns. `.babelrc` is local to your project so it won't be applied to `node_modules` in Jest.

Comment: thank you! that worked!   
i have third party dependency (`lodash-es`) and jest, configured with `babel` (as by default)
and jest was firing an error in lodash-es, so adding `transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!lodash-es/.*)']` forced lodash to transpile and now tests work!

NOTE: i use Typescript with ESM imports both in code and in tests, and run `tsc` only on precommit hook, so don't need to configure jest with typescript (or `ts-jest`) at all

Comment: when you say '.babelrc is local to your project so it won't be applied to node_modules in Jest.'   can you elaborate?... any docs that describe this?

Answer (score 5):

By accident I found a hack to let `pre-processor` process the whole `node_modules` what is usually forbidden:

> By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

```
transformIgnorePatterns:
[
    'node_modules'
]
```

Using this pattern seems to bypass the Jest internal check.

```
transformIgnorePatterns:
[
    '//node_modules'
]
```

It this a hack? Yes! Is this slow? Yes! But properly it can help someone who needs a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue when I was trying to test my app and some functions were using the file-type library.

I did jest configuration as below in my package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx",
      "node",
      "mjs"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": []
  },
```

I think the important thing is to only use "transformIgnorePatterns": [].

Setting **transformIgnorePatterns** to an empty array means Jest will transform every imported module using the specified transformer, in this case, **babel-jest**. By default, Jest does not transform anything in node_modules, which can lead to issues when a module (or its dependencies) uses ES6 imports.

If you only encounter this issue with a subset of modules, you can further refine **transformIgnorePatterns** to exclude only those specific modules from being ignored, but if the empty array works well and does not introduce other complications, you can stick with that.

Comment: It works. Except it is VERY slow as it transforms the whole node_modules, which can be large on some projects.

Comment: I have the same issue while doing automation test with jest. `skia-canvas` Index.node file cannot be imported, now it works

Answer (score 3):

For people suffering from this due to antd framework.

#### **Scenario**

You override antd DatePicker to use day js instead of default moment js.

You followed the instructions [here](https://ant.design/docs/react/replace-moment#DatePicker)

Now if you run your test, it will have that dreaded error

```
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

The reason for that is because of this

```
import generatePicker from "antd/es/date-picker/generatePicker";
import "antd/es/date-picker/style/index";
```

Specifically it is caused because of importing from **antd/es/**

The fix is to import from **antd/lib/** instead.

```
import generatePicker from "antd/lib/date-picker/generatePicker";
import "antd/lib/date-picker/style/index";
```

This fixes the test error, however, another problem that would arise is that this code have a bug. The **DatePicker** component now will not respect locales.

So the final solution is to add

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    ... other mappings here ...
    
    // Add this to fix the problem!
    "^antd/es/(.*)$": "antd/lib/$1",
  }
```

in your **jest.config.js** file

This will let you use **antd/es/** in your code but will replace it with **antd/lib/** on your tests.

Reference [here](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/23365#issuecomment-919813994)

Hope this helps anyone, this took me a while to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to solve it is and possible other subsequent issues regarding babel and typescript is to use [**ts-jest**](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest), quoted from [Jest's getting started](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript)

> However, there are some caveats to using TypeScript with Babel. Because TypeScript support in Babel is purely transpilation, Jest will not type-check your tests as they are run. If you want that, you can use ts-jest instead, or just run the TypeScript compiler tsc separately (or as part of your build process).

Answer (score 2):

I got stuck in the same situation. Due to I had a private untranspiled package which is based on TypeScript, and all my source files and test files were all applied with ECMA ( import syntax ), I encountered the following error as well.

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

The solutions I have tried.

- The above answers, such as use **transform**, **transformIgnorePatterns**, **moduleNameMapper** in `jest.config.ts`.
- Followed JEST official document, [Configuration Jest#transformignorepatterns-arraystring](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring), I used exactly the same method and even referred to the use case from [React Native Guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-react-native#transformignorepatterns-customization).
- Removed all `node_modules`, including cache, and reinstalled them.
- Used **react-scripts** and downgrade **jest** and **babel-jest** to 26 from 27. There was another issue that occurred.

After all, I found [ECMAScript Modules](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) from the JEST official document, the four steps perfectly solved my problem. I pasted their instructions here, however, you should take a look at the document itself.

1. Ensure you either disable code transforms by passing transform: {} or otherwise configure your transformer to emit ESM rather than the default CommonJS (CJS).
2. Execute node with --experimental-vm-modules, e.g. node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/.bin/jest or NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules npx jest etc.. On Windows, you can use cross-env to be able to set environment variables.
3. Beyond that, we attempt to follow node's logic for activating "ESM mode" (such as looking at type in package.json or mjs files), see their docs for details.
4. If you want to treat other file extensions (such as ts) as ESM, please use the extensionsToTreatAsEsm option.

Answer (score 2):

Solved mine by adding `"modules": "commonjs"` inside `.babelrc -> presets -> @babel/preset-env`

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": "commonjs"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

`package.json`

```
"jest": {
  "verbose": true,
  "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"],
  "testEnvironment": "node",
  "transformIgnorePatterns": [
    "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **tl;dr**: tsconfig.spec.json > `{ "compilerOptions": { "allowJs": true } }`

Did everything else mentioned here:

- transformIgnorePatterns
- add an additional pattern to the transform section
- ... much more that I reverted afterwards

Then I debugged into the transformer. First think I realized: the preconfigured workspace does not log anything, not even into ts-jest.log, not with `--verbose` or `--debug` and not even the warning, that would have been:

> Got a `.js` file to compile while `allowJs` option is not set to `true` (file: {{path}}). To fix this:
>
> - if you want TypeScript to process JS files, set `allowJs` to `true` in your TypeScript config (usually tsconfig.json)
> - if you do not want TypeScript to process your `.js` files, in your Jest config change the `transform` key which value is `ts-jest` so that it does not match `.js` files anymore

(see: [ts-jest-transformer.ts](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/blob/ccd58bc1d1874ccab25943be81b7ca8b70a05931/src/ts-jest-transformer.ts#L172))

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a different preset in your `jest.config.js` file.

Instead of using the default `"preset": "ts-jest"`, try use presets like `"preset": "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts"`. Based on the [documentation](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/presets/), it will:

> ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts
>
> TypeScript and JavaScript files (.ts, .tsx, .js, .jsx) will be transformed by ts-jest to CommonJS syntax.
> You'll need to set allowJs to true in your tsconfig.json file.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of answers here, but nothing worked for me. I was about to give up on `jest` but found a solution. I will document the steps as a checklist.

First, make sure `jest` is installed:

```
npm install --save-dev jest
```

Second, enable ESM in your `package.json` file:

```
{
  ...
 "type": "module"
}
```

Third, update the `test` property in the `package.json` file:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules ./node_modules/.bin/jest"
}
```

Following that, create the `jest.config.js` and add the following contents:

```
export default { transform: {} };
```

With that, run the jest again:

```
npm test
```

Comment: this setup causes the following error for me
`.\node_modules\.bin\jest:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me, but this error simply means you're not specifying correct jest path. Nowadays it would be `node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`

Answer (score 0):

### If you use direct paths:

Right now ts-jest version 28 & 29 is broken. I don't know all of the versions it affects, but it at least affects `28.1.3` - `29.1.0`. It is documented here: https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues/679

The bug is that specifying `moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"]` breaks jest in unexpected ways, including being essentially super mad at you for imports and exports. The fix is to change the line to `moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootdir>/src/"]` or remove it entirely. **Note: these solutions do not permit the original functionality**

The reason one might include this line is to allow direct paths so instead of `import { minute } from "../../../utils";` you can write   `import { minute } from "utils";` In my opinion this is very convenient. The above fixes will allow you to compile, but you will probably still get errors like `cannot find module "utils" in /some/directory/path`

The only fix I was able to find to get back my desired behaviour is using the moduleNameMapper option like so:

```
"moduleNameMapper": {
    '^utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
},
```

*credit to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67667249*

This means that you now have to explicitly specify which files you will reference with absolute imports. While not ideal, I could not get anything else to work

For reference, here is my complete jest.config.js file:

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-commonjs */
/** @type {import('@ts-jest/dist/types').InitialOptionsTsJest} */
module.exports = {
    preset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts",
    testEnvironment: "node",
    roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "node_modules/(?!variables/.*)"
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/dist/", "node_modules"],
    moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootdir>/src/"],
    setupFiles: ['dotenv/config'],
    collectCoverage: true,
    coverageDirectory: "coverage",
    extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
        "/src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
        '^utils(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/utils$1',
    },
    "transform": {
        "node_modules/variables/.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "ts-jest"
    },
};
```

For your `tsconfig.json`, you may want to consider the following settings:

```
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "module": "ESNext",
        "target": "ES2020",
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when installing NestJS following this documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/first-steps.

The fix was adding the missing `"preset": "ts-jest",` in the `package.json` file under `"jest"` configuration:

```
"jest": {
  ...
  "preset": "ts-jest",
  ...
}
```

Comment: What if it does not work?

Comment: @AlexBuznik it worked using this config: `"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [ "js", "json", "ts" ],
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }` and these versions of the dependencies: `"jest": "~29.5.0"`, `"ts-jest": "~29.1.0"`, `"@types/jest": "~29.5.2"`

Comment: Thanks! I think I was just editing .js tests and expecting them to work. Converted to TS and magic happened)

Answer (score 0):

Update the `test` property in the package.json file (the default is `react-scripts test`):

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### If you are using ts-jest

I was using ts-jest and encountered this error.
The key is that jest was still trying to use the JavaScript files that had been generated from the TypeScript tests. Once I deleted those, I was good to go.

Here's how I solved it.

0. Make sure you are using ESM syntax in your code
   and that your `package.json` contains this line

```json
{
  ...
 "type": "module"
}
```

1. Create a jest config file with this content

```js
// jest.config.ts
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  // [...]
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // or other ESM presets
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts with `ts-jest`
    // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process js/ts/mjs/mts with `ts-jest`
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
}

export default jestConfig
```

2. Delete any (previously) generated JavaScript files in the `tests` directory

(take care not to delete any of your own js files)

```bash
$ rm tests/*.js
```

3. Run jest again

```
bun run jest
```

Source: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem after migrating to NX monorepo v18, but with `node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/testing.mjs` file.

Angular library Jest config was not migrated/updated, here is config that worked for me:

Root `jest.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  testMatch: ['**/+(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|js)?(x)'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json' }],
  },
  resolver: '@nx/jest/plugins/resolver',
  coverageReporters: ['html'],
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
};

module.exports = config;
```

Angular Library `jest.config.js`

```
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {
  displayName: 'tests',
  preset: '../../jest.config.js',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['./src/test-setup.ts'],
  coverageDirectory: '../../coverage/libs/tests',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|mjs|js|html)$': [
      'jest-preset-angular',
      {
        tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json',
        stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.(html|svg)$',
      },
    ],
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)'],
};

module.exports = config;
```

Also used following commands to clear cache: `npx nx reset` and `npx jest --clearCache`.