# Why Jest failing on node-fetch giving syntax error on import

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, node-fetch

I'm trying to understand how to fix the following error using Jest in my unit tests in NodeJS.

The test run with this command `"test": "NODE_ENV=test jest spec/* -i --coverage --passWithNoTests",`

[image: Jest error]

I'm also using babel and this is my config

```
{
  "presets": [["@babel/env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }]],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
    ["babel-plugin-inline-import", { "extensions": [".gql"] }],
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }]
  ]
}
```

In package.json I have this

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "spec/**/*.js"
    ]
  },
```

I tried several guides online but cannot find a solution to this

Comment: Add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`.

Comment: This not working already tried same error happen

Comment: Is the code being executed on browser or Node?

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: This is NodeJS and the version is ~14.17.6

Answer (score 0):

You've got Jest successfully configured to transform *your* code, but it is not transforming modules that you're importing—in this case `node-fetch`, which has the `import` keyword in its source code (as seen in  your error). This is because, by default, Jest is configured [not to transform files in `node_modules`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring):

> transformIgnorePatterns [array]
>
> Default: ["/node_modules/", "\.pnp\.[^\/]+$"]
>
> An array of regexp pattern strings that are matched against all source file paths before transformation. If the file path matches any of the patterns, it will not be transformed.

You can set `transformIgnorePatterns` to exclude certain packages in `node_modules` with a `jest.config.js` like this:

```
const esModules = [
  'node-fetch',
  'data-uri-to-buffer',
  'fetch-blob',
  'formdata-polyfill',
].join('|');

module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    `/node_modules/(?!${esModules})`,
    '\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$',
  ],
};
```

(see https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/812#issuecomment-429420861)

Answer (score -1):

If you have .babelrc try to rename it to babel.config.js

Source:
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration#whats-your-use-case

but also this (there's more in the discussion)
[Jest won't transform the module - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781271/jest-wont-transform-the-module-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outsi)

Comment: The problem is that the error is inside the node-fetch 
as you see the screenshot is regarding inside the module

Comment: I read that by renaming it (if you didn't already), Babel will parse also the node_modules folder