# "Cannot use import statement outside a module" with Axios

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

I have a Vue.js application where two files contain:

`import axios from "axios"`

These files are located in src/lib within the application and include the import statement on their first line.

Running tests on Github causes Axios 1.0.0 to be installed, no matter what the package.json says, and now any test involving these files fails with the above error.

Changing the statement to `const axios = require("axios")` fails also; node_modules/axios/index.js contains an import statement on line 1 and the exception is thrown there.

A suggestion I've seen quite often for such issues is to add `"type": "module"` to package.json (which is at the same level as src/). This causes all tests to fail with a demand to rename vue.config.js as vue.config.cjs. Doing that gets me:  `Error: You appear to be using a native ECMAScript module configuration file, which is only supported when running Babel asynchronously`, which I do not understand.

Can anyone suggest what to do here?

Comment: it would be helpful if there is a code attached to this question.

Comment: What code in particular would you expect me to attach?

Comment: It is like where you are trying to import, How you are trying to import

Comment: Thanks. "How" is specified in the question above. As for "where", I'm not sure how that would help in this case. I'll put that in anyway.

Answer (score 289):

I was able to fix this error by forcing jest to import the commonjs axios build by adding

```json
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^axios$": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs"
    }
  },
```

to my `package.json`.  Other solutions using `transformIgnorePatterns` didn't work for me.

Comment: Someone buy this man a beer, this is the only solution that worked for me.  The `transformIgnorePatterns ` solution that is all over StackOverflow did not work, I spent hours on it. This is the only one that did. Thanks @rcbevans

Comment: Thank you so much: I was stuck with this error in a new test suite I was creating and adding axios to the `transformIgnorePatterns` was useless in this case. Your solution fixes my situation

Comment: Thank you, this also worked for me, but I had to add it to my jest.config.js file.

Comment: @spetry this can be used anywhere you configure jest in your project.  `package.json` under the jest key as in my answer, or a jest specific config file, like `jest.config.js`.

Comment: If you use react-scripts, this only works if you make changes to package.json.  I tried this in jest.config.js, and it has no effect.

Comment: Worked! The dist path may vary by version. For mine it was `axios/dist/axios.js` and I had to add a window global. But it seems to have worked!

Comment: how does package.json look with this change? (where did you put it?)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet anywhere at the top level of package.json

`
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
...
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "axios": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs",
    }
  },
}
`

Comment: @user926643 I think that's because you have two configuration locations. It's probably choosing the package.json in your case for some reason. For me it was the other way around and it didn't work until I added it into jest.config.js. I'm gonna merge my configurations now to avoid confusion.

Comment: Note that moduleNameMapper keys are regexes, so this answer will affect any file path containing "axios", even if it lives outside the `axios` module. You can scope it down with `"moduleNameMapper": { "^axios$": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs" }` – this is a bit safer and avoids unintentional re-mappings.

Comment: This Solution worked for me after trying several combinations of transformIgnorePatterns

Comment: This worked for me. I tried many things suggested in many other answers. `package.json` entry as above resolved the issue the test script threw while testing a component that used `axios`.

Comment: This solution works where the other solutions did not for whatever reason. Thank you.

Comment: Worked like a gem, I have added it in jest.config.js file and its working.

Comment: If I knew you before, I'd have saved a day!

Comment: I added this in jest.config.js file. Worked and saved me my other half of my day.  transformIgnorePatterns   did not work for me.

Comment: Works well in file `jest.config.js`, 
`module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^axios$": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs",
     },
}`

Answer (score 45):

The 1.x.x version of axios changed the module type from CommonJS to ECMAScript.

###### The 0.x.x version of axios index.js file

```js
module.exports = require('./lib/axios');
```

###### The 1.x.x version of axiox index.js file

```js
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
export default axios;
```

Basically, jest runs on Node.js environment, so it uses modules following the CommonJS.
If you want to use axios up to 1.x.x, you have to transpile the JavaScript module from ECMAScript type to CommonJS type.
Jest ignores `/node_modules/` directory to transform basically.

- https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring

So you have to override `transformIgnorePatterns` option.
There are two ways to override `transformIgnorePatterns` option.

##### jest.config.js

If your vue project uses `jest.config.js` file, you add this option.

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules/(?!axios)"],
  ...other options
};
```

##### package.json

If your vue project uses `package.json` file for jest, you add this option.

```json
{
  ...other options
  "jest": {
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules\/(?!axios)"]
  }
}
```

This regex can help you to transform axios module and ignore others under node_modules directory.

- https://regexper.com/#node_modules%5C%2F%28%3F!axios%29

Comment: This didn't work for me

Comment: Give me some context

Comment: Same here. Didnt work for me and I got the same error @Junhyunny

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: @quefro Give me some context

Comment: Got `found unknown escape character` when adding to package.json

Answer (score 30):

Updating the version of `jest` to v29 fixed this in my project. It could be the case that you have an incompatible `jest` version.

Comment: Bingo! This FINALLY got it working for me. Went from v27 to v29 

Comment: Nope, I have the last version and it does not work.

Comment: Thanks! [jest 28.0.0](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#2800): “Add support for package.json exports” solved the SyntaxError when my code is `"type": "commonjs"` and the default export of axios 1.0 is `"type": "module"`.

Comment: But, what is the reason for this error? Does anyone know the RCA?

Comment: This worked for me without any other changes. Using axios v1.6.7 and jest v27.5.1

Answer (score 23):

**Quick fix**

Update the npm run test script from

```
 "test": "react-scripts test",
```

to

```
 "test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"",
```

Comment: great ¡¡¡ this worked for me (I am using React)

Comment: work form me, react-script project

Answer (score 21):

This works for me:

Add **moduleNameMapper** in your **jest.config.js**

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    axios: 'axios/dist/node/axios.cjs',
},
```

Comment: you are a savior man, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the #1 answer. Worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I faced with the same problem. And firstly used variant (inside package.json file):

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "axios": "axios/dist/node/axios.cjs"
    }
  },
```

But for mocking I use axios-mock-adapter. And I got the error:

**TypeError: mock.onGet is not a function**

I changed code to:

```
"jest": {
       "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)"
        ]
     }
```

And this solution works.
The versions:

- "axios": "^1.4.0"
- "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.21.5"
- "@types/axios-mock-adapter": "^1.10.0"

Answer (score 4):

With NestJs if you are facing this issue, then upgrade your package.json with following package versions.

```
 "jest": "^29.0.0" 

 "ts-jest": "^29.0.0"
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues and was able to solve this by using [jest-mock-axios](https://github.com/knee-cola/jest-mock-axios) library

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same issue after upgrading axios to version 1.6.0.
You can add the below lines to your jest.config.js:

```json
"jest": {
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "axios": require.resolve("axios"),
  }
},
```

Answer (score 2):

I experience similar problem but the error is caused by `jest`.
All the tests trying to import `axios` fail and throw the same exception:

```
Test suite failed to run
    Jest encountered an unexpected token
    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html
    Details:
    /monorepo/node_modules/axios/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import axios from './lib/axios.js';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
      1 | import { describe, expect, it } from '@jest/globals'
    > 2 | import axios from 'axios'
```

The solution is simply tell `jest` that `axios` should be transformed with `babel`:

```js
const esModules = ['lodash-es', 'axios'].join('|')

# add these entries in module.exports
transform: {
  [`^(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: 'babel-jest',
},
transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!(${esModules}))`],
```

Note: I'm using Quasar Vue and this is their implementation.

Comment: Thanks. For the moment I've worked around it locally by downgrading Axios, but will try this to see if it helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Which file do you add this to?

Comment: In jest.config.js

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to add the following line to the moduleNameMapper object in the jest config:

```
axios: '<rootDir>/node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs',
```

Answer (score 2):

For Axios, add the following code to your package.json;

```
    "jest": {
       "transformIgnorePatterns": [
          "/node_modules/(?!(axios)/)"
        ]
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, fixed by applying the following changes to my packages.json file.

```
"test": "react-scripts test"
```

Fix #1: Passing transformIgnorePatterns as command line arguments - recommended by earlier users.

```
"test": "react-scripts test --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!axios)/\"
```

Fix #2 (*My recommendation*): Adding/ Updating jest configuration in package.json file

```
"jest": {
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules\/(?!axios)"
        ]
    },
```

The above recommendation works well and comes in handy to include any further transformIgnorePatterns

Example:

```
"jest": {
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "/node_modules/(?!(axios|antd|@ant-design|rc-.+?|@babel/runtime)).+(js|jsx)$"
        ]
    },
```

In above snippet, if a module matches one of the specified names (axios, antd, etc.), it is excluded from transformation.

If a module does not match any of the specified names, it is not excluded and will undergo the usual transformation process.

This would be a good read if someone wants to understand about transformIgnorePatterns: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach when working with Jest and Typescript, you can mock the individual functions you require for your test:

```
import axios from 'axios'

jest.mock('axios', () => ({
  post: jest.fn(),
  get: jest.fn()
}))

const mockedAxios = axios as jest.Mocked<typeof axios>

mockedAxios.post.mockResolvedValue({})
```

Although this approach worked for me, asking babel to transpile axios also did the trick:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
   '/node_modules/(?!(axios)/).*'
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:
*package.json*

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!axios)/"]
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with axios 1.6.0

I've created a jest.config.js file and exported the config like this:

```
const config = {
moduleNameMapper: {
    axios: require.resolve("axios"),
 }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Comment: and did that solve the problem for you?

Comment: my answer addressed the question title: "Cannot use import statement outside a module, with Axios", answering the question of "suggesting solutions to resolve the issue" and it worked in my case.
adding this configuration lets Jest run without failing and solves the issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, it works fine when changing **axios** to **fetch**.

**axios** (Fail)

```
 try {
        const response = await axios("api/fruit/all");
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
  }
```

**Fetch** (Works fine)

```
  try {
    const response = await fetch("api/fruit/all",{method:"GET"});
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
```