# Unit testing services that use HttpModule

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am doing some unit tests on my services, so far so good but I came across an issue with a service using HttpModule.
My real module imports the HttpModule from the @nestjs/axios package, so that my service can use the Httpservice to make calls.

My mock module for the tests, where I tried puting the HttpService in the providers array :

```
export const franceCasseMockModule = {
  controllers: [FranceCasseController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AmqpConnection,
      useValue: jest.fn(),
    },
    {
      provide: FtpService,
      useValue: jest.fn(),
    },
    HttpService,
   ...others services
```

When running the test, I have this error :  A circular dependency has been detected inside RootTestModule. Please, make sure that each side of a bidirectional relationships are decorated with "forwardRef()".

I have tried using the madge package to check for circular dependencies but this one does not appear.
If I remove the http calls from  my real service, so that I don't have to add HttpService in the providers of my mock module, it works fine.
if I try to mock the HttpService like I did for the FtpService, I have this error :

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the FranceCasseService . Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [1] is available in the RootTestModule context. (which is the HttpService)
If I try to import the HttpModule (saw that it was considered a bad practice when unit testing but was curious about the outcome), I have the following error :

Nest cannot create the RootTestModule instance.
The module at index [0] of the RootTestModule "imports" array is undefined.

I am out of solutions to try here, if anyone can bring some light on this, it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who encountered the same issue, I found a solution that resolved the problem. Here are the steps to address the issue:

#### 1. Update Packages

Ensure that you have updated relevant packages. In my case, the `nestjs/axios` package was using axios as a peer dependency with a higher version, and the jest runner was also on the latest version.

[image: Update Packages]

#### 2. Check Jest Configuration

Inspect your Jest configuration (`jest.config.cjs`) to verify that you are not using the CommonJS (cjs) version of the axios client. If present, remove any content related to the cjs version.

[image: Jest Configuration]

For those wondering about the origin of such code, I found a thread that might have inspired this solution in our codebase. [Link to Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73958968/cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-with-axios)

#### 3. Dont specify HttpModule in HttpService provider section

Make sure you wont specify `HttpService` in your app module declaration. Ensure that you specify only `HttpModule` from `@nestjs/axios` in your imports sections, By doing so `HttpService` become injectable into your services.

By following these steps, the issue related to "Cannot use import statement outside a module with axios" should be resolved. If you have any questions or face further issues, feel free to ask.