# Jest : SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, jestjs, es6-modules, ts-jest, commonjs

I'm writting tests in a Node/TS project, which is a backend API (no babel, no webpack, no react/angular/vue/...).
My project is then a CommonJS project.

I'm using Jest as a test framework.

Everything was going well since I had to use the npm package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type)[file-type] which is an ESM.

At runtime everything is ok, my API works perfectly fine.

But the tests I wrote using it, even when it's mocked, are failing with this error:

```bash
Details:

/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/file-type/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as strtok3 from 'strtok3';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I've tried many combination of configurations in my jest.config.ts, but nothing works.

Does anyone has already managed to use an EMS package in a CommonJS project and write tests using it?

Thank you so much.

jest.config.ts:

```js
reset: "ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts", // tries "ts-jest" and "ts-jest/presets/default-esm"
testEnvironment: "node",
transform: {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest"
  },
transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "node_modules/",
    "\\.pnp\\.[^\\/]+$"
  ],
```

```bash
npx jest path/to/my/file.test.ts
```

should run the test suite but fails with:

```bash
Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

Here's what you can do:
 • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
 • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
For information about custom transformations, see:
https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

Details:

/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/file-type/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import * as strtok3 from 'strtok3';
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at new Script (node:vm:94:7)
    at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
    at Runtime._execModule (/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1399:25)
    at Runtime._loadModule (/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1022:12)
    at Runtime.requireModule (/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:882:12)
    at Runtime.requireModuleOrMock (/home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1048:21)
    at /home/bonjourjohn/projects/arpilabe/ged-backend/src/services/FileTypeService.ts:8:25
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest won't transform the module - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61781271/jest-wont-transform-the-module-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outsi)

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way to make it work.

Instead of mocking the package, which apparently still triggers the import of its dependencies somehow, I simply used the `moduleNameMapper` configuration.

I wrote a stub that includes only the functions I use from the package, put it somewhere in my `__mock__` folders, and I configured Jest to use this stub instead of the real package:

```json
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "file-type": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/file-type.ts",
  },
```